# How to create java gui animation?

Tags: java, animation, user-interface

I have a line drawn in my gui and I want to put the arrow moving on the line. It is abit of animation and I can't seem to find it on the google. I hope you guys can help me out with Java gui animation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Thread` with a loop inside its `run()` method. On each step of the loop change the position of the arrow a little bit, repaint the user interface (or only the part that you know has changed) and wait for about 30ms or so.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of UI animation is far beyond the scope of a single answer, you could literally write a book about it.  Fortunately somebody has - [Filthy Rich Clients](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Filthy-Rich-Clients-Developing-Applications/dp/0132413930).